# Query in implementing queue in linked list in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, queue

I have tried to implement queue using linked list. This is the code i wrote. When i try to use the disp() method i get a infinite loop running. I am not able to find the error in the logic. I fail to understand how the line `while(temp!=NULL)` and incrementing the temp never ends.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int x;
    node *next;
};

class queue{
    node *front,*rear;
    public:
        queue(){
            front = NULL;
            rear= NULL;
        }
        
        void enqueue(int x){
            node *temp=new node;
            temp->x=x;
            temp->next=NULL;
            if(rear==NULL){
                rear=temp;
                front = temp;
            }
            else{
                rear->next=temp;
                rear=temp;
            }
        }
        
        int dequeue(){
            node *temp =front;
            if(temp!=NULL){
                int x =temp->x;
                temp=temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return x;
            }
            else{
                return -1e7;
            }
        }
        
        void disp(){
            node *temp=front;
            while(temp!=NULL){
                cout<<temp->x<<" ";
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            
        }
};

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    queue obj;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        obj.enqueue(x);
    }
    
    int x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    obj.enqueue(x);
    obj.enqueue(y);
    
    obj.dequeue();
    obj.disp();
}
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Which element of your queue is `dequeue()` supposed to delete?  Always the second element?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for explaining. Understood my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dequeue` is not properly dequeueing the first element:

```
        node *temp =front;
        if(temp!=NULL){
            int x =temp->x;
            temp=temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return x;
        }
```

`temp = temp->next` makes `temp` point to the second node and in the next line you delete that second node, instead of the first one.

Make the second node the new `front` and delete the old `front`:

```
        node *temp = front;
        if(temp != NULL){
            int x = temp->x;
            front = temp->next;   // <---
            delete temp;
            return x;
        }
```